# can't find the problem with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, debugging, exception

i have a problem with my application tha some times return this error in console, but i can't find the origin (all Unknown Source). THe application seems to work properly after this error, but i want to understand what appening... How i can do?

Thank you and sorry for my english!

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Is there a **cause** to this exception?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the source of `BasicListUI.updateLayoutState()`, this can only happen when the list being displayed changes size while the method executes.

The most likely reason is that you're modifying the model from outside the [event dispatch thread](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html). This is a serious problem, since it could result in all kinds of bizarre behaviour and even corrupt data.

To fix them problem, use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) whenever you need to manipulate the model from outside the EDT.

Comment: Hello, after 3 hours testing my app with SwingUtilities.invokeLater(), i can say that the problem is solved!!! Thank you very much again @Michael Borgwardt

Answer (score 1):

This type of error is sometimes caused by updating GUI components **off** the EDT, when it should be done **on** the EDT.

If fixing any code that violates that principle does not solve the problem, I suggest you try to prepare an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) & post it to the thread.